# How many points is each chess piece worth?

Tags: evaluation, pieces, point-value

I am a beginner at chess; please answer this question for me.

> How many points is each chess piece worth?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

**Individual pieces:**

**Pawn** - 1 point

**Knight** - 3 points

**Bishop** - 3 points

**Rook** - 5 points

**Queen** - 9 points

**Piece combinations:**

**Rook and Knight** - 7.5 points

**Rook and Bishop** - 8 points

**Pair of Rooks** - 10 points

**Three minor pieces** - 10 points

**Rook and two minor pieces** - 11 points

N.B. The values may vary because of circumstances, but these are the basic values.

Comment: (-1) The 1-3-3-5-9 guideline is widely accepted and taught, but I've never heard of the piece combination values, nor do I see the point as it clearly depends on the position. Do you have a credible source for those values?

Comment: Yeah. Widely taught isn't a credible source either. But you're right, it all depends on the position. I don't have a credible source. But feel free to find one.

Comment: Very late on this, these combination values are quite arbitrary of course, there is one specific one I want to touch on: two rooks. In general two rooks are considered less than twice as strong as one rook. There have been different explanation attempts, one of them is about the redundancy of multiple rooks.

In practice this means that if one side has two rooks and the other one (with whatever other piece imbalances) mostly the side with two rooks tries to trade one pair of rooks for that exact reason.

Comment: The bishop pair is considered worth half a pawn. And bishops are often sightly preferred to knights (by 0.25 points)

Answer (score 39):

The answer by MikroDel gives the commonly-used "Reinfeld values" of pawn=1, bishop=knight=3, rook=5, and queen=9 (kings are essentially worth an infinite number of points, because the game ends if it is lost). While this is a good guide, chess is rarely that simple. Many books will give the value of bishops as 3.5 instead of 3, simply because they are often much stronger than knights in endgames and open middle-games.

There are other things to take into account as well. For example, bishops are much stronger if you own both of yours, but you opponent has already lost/traded one or both of theirs. The nature of the position can also affect the worth of individual pieces, as a position that is completely blocked up might leave a bishop with no useful squares to go to while a knight may be able to jump straight over the obstruction.

Another example of how the Reinfeld values can be misleading is that 3 minor pieces (bishops and knights) are often more powerful than a single queen, provided that they are used properly.

For some further reading, you might also want to take a look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chess_piece_relative_value which has a much more detailed explanation.

Comment: "While this is a good guide, chess is rarely that simple." that was in no way the idea of my answer. Thats why I wrote that the evaluation depends on position. And also have extra posted an explanation what was meant

Comment: Even more detailed than the wikipedia page is Larry Kaufman's [Evaluation of Material Imbalances](http://home.comcast.net/~danheisman/Articles/evaluation_of_material_imbalance.htm).

Comment: @MikroDel Yes, that part of my comment was intended to reinforce what you said about Reinfeld's values only being a guide.

Comment: Bishops and Knights are better in closed games, whereas rooks are typically better in open games. Something to consider when trading that knight and bishop for a rook.

Comment: Not a fan of the "king is worth infinite points" bit, because it completely abandons any attempt at gauging the actual relative strength of the king. If all that system does is gauge importance, then wouldn't a lone pawn that's currently positioned to prevent a mate be worth infinite points as well?

Comment: @BigHomie Personally I'd be more concerned with your own strengths and weaknesses with each piece, as well as your opponent's, than with how the board is stacked on any given turn.

Comment: @b1nary.atr0phy you're not wrong, but at the same time it's hard to gauge the value of pieces over the entire game. For example, the king is often said to be worth about the same as a rook in many characters but significantly less as an active piece while there are more piecesbon the board. So which value to use? And should we value knights relative to an open, closed, middle game or endhame position? And so on and so forth. For the king especially, you really need to see a position to make a proper estimation of value.

Comment: In chess you can use values to a) find the comparative advantage in a position b) find if a trade is advantageous. These are not exactly the same. E.g. if you have both bishops, the opponent has only one, then trading bishops is not to your advantage. King’s value is irrelevant in both these cases because kings are never traded and their value in valuing a position even out because both sides always have their kings. If one is valuing a flank or value the pieces in the area of action in a pawn end game, probably king's value is useful. I haven't  seen anything like this outside chess engines.

Answer (score 19):

**Pawn** - 1 point

**Bishop**, **Knight** - 3 Pawns

**Rook** - 5 Pawns

**Queen** - 9 Pawns

The evaluation depends on the position.

In some situation you will find it equal or good to give you Rook and Pawn (6 Pawns) for Bishop and Knight (6 Pawns). But it is also possible that two light pieces are more valuable than Rook and Pawn.

The value of pieces given to you will be a good **start point** to evaluate your position.

Answer (score 16):

There's a great analysis/article about this by GM Larry Kaufman available [here.](https://www.danheisman.com/evaluation-of-material-imbalances.html)

To summarize:

- Pawn = 1
- Knight = Bishop = 3.25
- Bishop Pair = 7(+0.25 for each bishop.)
- Rook = 5
- Queen = 9.75

There's also a lot more detail in the article about what situations favor which groups of pieces. For example, when B+N is better than R+P, or when Q+P is better than R+R, etc.

Answer (score 10):

The standard is usually to compare pieces to each other (i.e how many pawns is a knight worth, a bishop, a queen etc.?

Another way is to determine piece value dynamically using the idea of **"absolute/potential activity"** and **"nominal activity"**. This idea is based on the number of squares any given piece controls (and I believe is partly how computer engines determine piece values). I believe it is also called **mobility** by some chess players. Let me explain:

First a few definitions (these are my own, created for the sake of the explanation):

1. **Activity** = The number of squares any piece controls
2. **Control** = (referring to squares) when a square(s) cannot be occupied by an opponent piece or pawn due the danger of it being captured
3. **Center** = The squares e4, d4, e5 and d5

Each piece (lets ignore pawns for the moment) has an **absolute activity** value and a **nominal activity** value. The Reinfeld system given above is essentially the former, and it describes the value of the piece in its best condition (i.e where it controls the greatest number of squares). For the sake of convenience we can say that this condition is when the piece is in the center, as all pieces control the maximal number of squares when placed there (try it out with a few pieces and see).

We can quickly formulate some absolute activity values for the pieces by counting the number of squares each piece controls when placed in the center (of an empty board):

- **Queen**: Controls **27** squares
- **Rook**: Controls **14** squares
- **Bishop**: Controls **13** squares
- **Knight**: Controls **8** squares

*Note that I've omitted the pawn and the king, this is because they are special, and I will deal with them a bit later.

Now looking at the above we see that the Reinfeld scores were more or less based on this derivation, with the apparent exception of the bishop which seems to be closer to a rook than a knight (the thing which is omitted here, is the fact that a bishop can only control squares of one color; hence its low Reinfeld value).

Other common ideas also become clear with this formulation, e.g the idea of the "two bishops" advantage, which, according to this, would be close to a queen in strength! (13*2 = 26). However, this formulation is only half-complete, because in a real game things are rarely so perfect and ideal as an empty board with your pieces huddled in the center.

Thus we introduce the idea of "nominal activity", which is simply the activity of a piece in a given position. Remember that activity = the number of squares a piece controls. Nominal activity can be constantly in flux (since the position is inevitability bound to change) but is a useful concept when compared against the "absolute activity", for three reasons:

- It helps you determine whether to trade pieces (and also *which* pieces to trade)
- It helps you decide what kinds of positions to create (this is where common chess principles like "knights favor closed positions, bishops favor open ones" come from)
- It helps you figure out which piece's position you need to improve first ("Knights before bishops" comes from this)

Many, many common ideas can be elucidated from this formulation (mostly because it is so fundamental to the game). Consider the idea of a positional sacrifice, it is simply a move which gives up material in exchange for one's piece(s) to get closer to its(their) absolute activity.

This brings me to the pawns. The pawns don't really have activity in the same way pieces do, instead they are used to determine **terrain**, i.e the "positional factors" on the board which determine nominal activity. In that sense, they are used to limit or increase the nominal activity of *other* pieces (this why you move the pieces first, then the pawns, because its usually faster to move a piece to a better square than to improve a piece by making a pawn move). Pawns serve other purposes as well, of course, but in the context of this question I think this will suffice.

So to summarize:

1. **Absolute activity: the greatest number of squares a piece can potentially control**
2. **Nominal activity: the number of squares a piece controls in a given position**
3. **Piece Value: a dynamic measurement based upon how close a piece's nominal activity is to its absolute activity**

EDIT:

Notice how easy (and accurate, and logical) piece combination values become when using this system.

- 2 Rooks (28) > 1 Queen (27)
- 2 Knights + 1 Bishop (29) > 1 Queen
- 2 Bishops + 1 Knight (34) >> 1 Queen
- 2 Bishops (26) >> 2 Knights (16)
- Bishop + Knight (21) >> Rook + pawn (~16)
- etc.

Also notice how nominal activity can help determine which pieces are better in the endgame (the pieces whose nominal activity is greatly affected by pawns will improve in the endgame)

- Bishop (eg ~13) > Knight (eg ~8)
- Rook (eg ~14) < Bishop + pawn(eg ~15)
- etc.

Answer (score 9):

Computer Chess programs provide an [evaluation of pieces relative to the strength of a pawn](http://chessprogramming.wikispaces.com/Point+Value), which compliment's Dave's answer nicely.  To summarize:

### Piece: Range of Values

1. Pawn:   100
2. Knight: 300-400
3. Bishop: 300-400
4. Rook:   500-600
5. Queen:  880-1200
6. King:   10000*

*Kings are given a large actual value to simplify the search behavior, but essentially have infinite value, as the game ends if they are 'killed'.

Comment: Regarding the King, see thb answer

Answer (score 9):

Though one cannot trade one's king for other considerations -- and in this sense the king cannot be evaluated -- the king still has a practical strength as an attacking and defending piece in the many concrete positions in which no immediate mate is in view -- especially during the endgame.  This strength can indeed be evaluated.  World Champion Emanuel Lasker [regarded the king](http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=King_%28chess%29&oldid=552396027) to be one point stronger than a minor piece.

Thus, in this sense, if a knight or bishop has a strength of three, and if we accept Lasker's advice, then *the king's strength will be four.*

Answer (score 5):

Don't use the system, it hurts chess players into thinking that one bishop is **always** better than a knight or a rook is **always** better than a bishop.

Comment: @user8213 It's true that the values depend on the position, but it's also true that it's more helpful for a beginning player to know that a rook is worth about 5 and a bishop is worth about 3 than to simply tell them that the values can vary. They should learn the general rules before they learn the exceptions to those rules.

Answer (score 5):

Unfortunately many answers and numerous systems given in Wikipedia can confuse amateurs because depending on the position type some pieces are stronger or weaker (open, closed positions, pawn structures, bad piece, good piece, etc.) So, we can talk only about values statistically and when other things being equal, otherwise the system becomes complicated. It can be remedied by giving pieces more precise fractional values.

Here goes **a possible approximation based on quarters** (also see below the old dedicated chess computer system based on halves - also put in boldface):

- **Knight/Bishop = 3.25 pawn** (at pro level bishops are often 0.25 higher; the reverse might hold for amateurs!)
- **Rook = 4.75 pawns**
- **Queen = 9.25 pawns**
- **Two Bishops = 7 pawns** (they usually boost each other covering both dark and light squares)
- **Two Doubled Pawns = 1.5 pawns** (it is usually a weakness)

However, even the general evaluation with fractions may backfire, and the player should account for general chess principles (you can find them in Silman's textbooks for example) and make proper calculations in each specific position. Thus, sometimes a pawn needs to be promoted to a knight which means a knight (3.25 pawns) can be better than a Queen (9.25 pawns), albeit extremely rarely. Everything depends on a specific position. Players should invest efforts in learning position types, bad pieces, good pieces, etc.

Examples of mistakes that might arise out of rough non-fractional values:

- Three minor pieces (3+3+3) are equal to the Queen (9). No. They are usually slightly stronger, say, by 0.5 pawns (3.25 + 3.25 + 3.25 = 9.75)
- Two minor pieces (3+3) are equal to a Rook and Pawn (5+1). No. Two minor pieces are usually stronger by around 0.75 pawns (3.25 + 3.25 = 6.5)
- Treating a rook like 5 or even 5.5 pawns before endgame. That's also a bad idea. Rooks become very strong only towards endgame or sometimes during kingside attacks.
- Perhaps the worst mistake of amateurs is that bishops are stronger than knights. No! They are only statistically better in high quality games but for amateurs it's probably the other way round as they are prone to missing tactics.
- Rook and Knight = 7.5 pawns = Rook + 2.5 pawns. No. It might hold for some endgames but outside the context it's an unnecessary complication.

To prevent such basic mistakes the average fractional values above can be used. However, there's no quick fix or short cut, and chess principles are important as well as specific positions where general values will no longer apply. That said, using more precise values with fractions should be less detrimental than teaching amateurs this: 1, 3, 3, 5, 9. Carefree rounding to get nice numbers leads to the mistakes outlined above. Still people prefer nice round numbers while even **the old dedicated chess computer system based on halves** is superior:

- **Knight/Bishop = 3 pawns**
- **Rook = 4.5 panws**
- **Queen = 8.5 pawns**
- **Bishop Pair = 6.5 pawns**
- **Doubled Pawns = 1.5 pawns**

If fractions are not used, precision is lost. It should be noted that the modern systems of chess engines are complicated with many variables. Hence, using them to explain piece values to amateurs might confuse and lead to errors. As to using nice round numbers, let me emphasize it one more time: It often leads to mistakes and creates necessity of weird, complicated and even wrong calculations and memorization of values of piece combinations rather than focusing on chess principles, on types of positions, on when the knight is better than the bishop and vice versa, etc.

Answer (score 4):

This is a very sensible question for a beginner to ask, but as you progress beyond being a beginner, as I hope you do, you will come to realize that it has no answer.

Comment: I agree. +1. I don't think there's such thing as points in chess. It depends on the position.

Comment: it has answer, it's just different because it's position specific

Answer (score 4):

Dider gives an answer based on the maximum activity of the pieces when they are placed at the center of an empty board.
One could continue this analysis evaluating the activity at other locations of the board, building an 8x8 matrix for each piece. And comparing two extreme cases: empty board vs fully crowded board.

The resulting matrices are:

```
    Empty board (free piece)                Crowded board (blocked piece)   
    ------------------------                -----------------------------
Pawn    x  x  x  x  x  x  x  x          Pawn    x  x  x  x  x  x  x  x      
        1  2  2  2  2  2  2  1                  1  2  2  2  2  2  2  1      
        1  2  2  2  2  2  2  1                  1  2  2  2  2  2  2  1      
        1  2  2  2  2  2  2  1                  1  2  2  2  2  2  2  1      
        1  2  2  2  2  2  2  1                  1  2  2  2  2  2  2  1      
        1  2  2  2  2  2  2  1                  1  2  2  2  2  2  2  1      
        1  2  2  2  2  2  2  1                  1  2  2  2  2  2  2  1      
Pawn    x  x  x  x  x  x  x  x          Pawn    x  x  x  x  x  x  x  x      
mean = 7/4 squares                      mean=7/4 squares                

kNight  2  3  4  4  4  4  3  2          kNight  2  3  4  4  4  4  3  2      
        3  4  6  6  6  6  4  3                  3  4  6  6  6  6  4  3      
        4  6  8  8  8  8  6  4                  4  6  8  8  8  8  6  4      
        4  6  8  8  8  8  6  4                  4  6  8  8  8  8  6  4      
        4  6  8  8  8  8  6  4                  4  6  8  8  8  8  6  4      
        4  6  8  8  8  8  6  4                  4  6  8  8  8  8  6  4      
        3  4  6  6  6  6  4  3                  3  4  6  6  6  6  4  3      
kNight  2  3  4  4  4  4  3  2          kNight  2  3  4  4  4  4  3  2      
mean = 21/4 squares, N~3P               mean=21/4 squares, N~3P             

Bishop  7  7  7  7  7  7  7  7          Bishop  1  2  2  2  2  2  2  1      
        7  9  9  9  9  9  9  7                  2  4  4  4  4  4  4  2      
        7  9  11 11 11 11 9  7                  2  4  4  4  4  4  4  2      
        7  9  11 13 13 11 9  7                  2  4  4  4  4  4  4  2      
        7  9  11 13 13 11 9  7                  2  4  4  4  4  4  4  2      
        7  9  11 11 11 11 9  7                  2  4  4  4  4  4  4  2      
        7  9  9  9  9  9  9  7                  2  4  4  4  4  4  4  2      
Bishop  7  7  7  7  7  7  7  7          Bishop  1  2  2  2  2  2  2  1      
mean=35/4 squares, B~5P                 mean=49/16 squares, B~1.75P         

King    3  5  5  5  5  5  5  3          King    3  5  5  5  5  5  5  3      
        5  8  8  8  8  8  8  5                  5  8  8  8  8  8  8  5      
        5  8  8  8  8  8  8  5                  5  8  8  8  8  8  8  5      
        5  8  8  8  8  8  8  5                  5  8  8  8  8  8  8  5      
        5  8  8  8  8  8  8  5                  5  8  8  8  8  8  8  5      
        5  8  8  8  8  8  8  5                  5  8  8  8  8  8  8  5      
        5  8  8  8  8  8  8  5                  5  8  8  8  8  8  8  5      
King    3  5  5  5  5  5  5  3          King    3  5  5  5  5  5  5  3      
mean=105/16 squares, K~3.75P            mean=105/16 squares, K~3.75P            

Rook    14 14 14 14 14 14 14 14         Rook    2  3  3  3  3  3  3  2      
        14 14 14 14 14 14 14 14                 3  4  4  4  4  4  4  3      
        14 14 14 14 14 14 14 14                 3  4  4  4  4  4  4  3      
        14 14 14 14 14 14 14 14                 3  4  4  4  4  4  4  3      
        14 14 14 14 14 14 14 14                 3  4  4  4  4  4  4  3      
        14 14 14 14 14 14 14 14                 3  4  4  4  4  4  4  3      
        14 14 14 14 14 14 14 14                 3  4  4  4  4  4  4  3      
Rook    14 14 14 14 14 14 14 14         Rook    2  3  3  3  3  3  3  2      
mean=14 squares, R~7P                   mean=7/2 squares, R~2P
```

The board starts in a "half-crowded" state, and becomes less crowded as the game advances. 
The numerical values found on books and publications lie between these extreme cases.
Looking at the high fluctuations, one can understand why so many people say that it all depends (heavily!) on the position.

Comment: Your bishop on the crowded board looks wrong on the far right side; those 4s should be 2s.

Comment: And you didn't put the queen in - it would, by this measure, be the sum of the rook and the bishop.  So, between 12 and 3.75 pawns.

Comment: D M: I have corrected the wrong numbers of the bishop, thanks. According to this model of activity and mobility, the Queen should be the sum Q=R+B. But that is not in accordance with the "official" numbers; the real Queen is usually considered more than R+B, so she must have properties that are not covered by this model.

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by "crowded board"? The numbers for your crowded board matrices otherwise make no sense to me.

Comment: @itub: A completely "crowded" board is only an idealization, because a real board will have at most 32 of the 64 squares occupied. Perhaps we should imagine crowded spots or regions.

Comment: For instance, a bishop placed in a crowded spot is fully sorrounded by other pieces (friend or enemy) and cannot use its feature of controlling long diagonals; it can only control the 4 adjacent squares of the same color.

This number 4 turns into a lower 2 if the bishop is at the border and has only 2 neighbors, or 1 if it is at the corner. 
When the game starts and during the early opening, when the captures have not yet begun, crowded spots are equally frequent as free spots.
So the "power" of the bishop (according to this model) lies between ~1.75P and ~5P, mean=3.3P

Answer (score 3):

I'd say in general bishops get 3.5 knights 3, queen 9, rooks 5 and the king doesn't get evaluated because, as everyone said he doesn't have a definite value, but you could say he's quite important in the endgame(around practical value 4).

Now the values **change.**
So in a closed position knights are stronger than bishops, often stronger than rooks even.
In half open-open positions bishops are stronger than knights but **2 bishops** basically increase each others strength.

Another example, in positions with a small number of pawns and light pieces, 2 rooks are often better than a queen, whereas in positions with a lot of other pieces a queen is (most often) better.

So it all really depends on the position. And my words are true only if you can actually use your pieces as good as possible, or something close to that. :)

Answer (score 3):

Initial values are Pawn - 1 point, Bishop, Knight - 3 Pawns, Rook - 5 Pawns, Queen - 9 Pawns.

These values change in relation to the position and the configuration of pieces on either side.  Pieces on good squares are worth more than pieces on bad squares.  Point count is merely a rough, basic guide to the strength of each side; more important is the placement and activity of the pieces - this is where judgement of material imbalances becomes important.  You can't simply say that a Queen is equal to 3 minor pieces or 2 rooks; the position will dictate the relative values.

Answer (score 2):

Chess pieces and their points:

```
queen - 9
rook - 5
bishop - 3.5
knight - 3
pawn - 1
```

If you need any more help, search on Google for Chess pieces and their points.

Comment: Even if this is a beginner's approximation (which is good enough for somebody starting out in the game), it is bit inaccurate to assign the king zero points, or for that matter, assign points to a king at all as you don't "use" him to count material trades or captures.

Comment: Well, @shivsky I am a beginner. But thanks for the information.

Comment: @TheWildMan I made an edit. It should be better now. Cheers.

Answer (score 2):

Queen 10
Rook 5
Bishop 3.5
Knight 3 (debatable)
Pawn 1

Comment: This answer does not give any reasoning or references. However, these precise values are not mentioned in other answers, so it is not a duplicate answer and probably could be improved.

Answer (score 2):

Pawn = 1
Knight = 3+-1/3
Bishop = 3+-1/2
Rook = 5
Queen = 9
King = Infinite
Back when my brother and I played chess in the early-middle 70's (when Fischer & Spasky were all the rage), this is the point system I remember reading about in a book on chess (I can't remember the book).

Comment: "First Book of Chess"?

Comment: Early 70s.. must be playing chess for so many years. Even my elder brother and I playrd chess in 1987 and then till today no games so far..

Answer (score -3):

Value of pieces varies from position to position.
It's just a random number assigned to them which ideally has no value.
And if you use so called values then there would be number of shortcomings on combination of pieces.
For a very basic way, do this:
Put any piece on one of centre squares on a empty board and count number of squares it controls.
Pawn: 1
Knight: 8
Bishop: 13
Rook: 14
Queen: 27
That's just for very rough idea not in any sense real value.

Comment: This answer is not based on logical analysis. Modern chess has been subjected to experiments and research by many researchers and even mathematics experts.

Comment: @ShadYantra As I said that it's not real and give than very rough estimation which is also actually nothing. Main thing is it depends on position which is absolutely correct.

Comment: And what about the real games played on Dashpaad (10x10) boards. How will you analyze the pieces.. Impossible!!

Comment: @ShadYantra You don't seem to read properly. I already said that the values are purely relative as it only depends on position but for a moment I am giving a very rough (which actually doesn't make sense but comparisons is all about assumptions) idea of pieces. I already said that it is no serious talk.

Comment: Hmm. I agreed and never said you were wrong.